# Soft and hard copies of a single product in Drupal Commerce?

Tags: commerce, files

I am setting up products for an online store using Drupal Commerce. Some of the products (eg. books, music) require an option for both hard copies and soft copies so that customers can choose one or the other. I would like certain products to have a drop down in which customers can choose either "Hard Copy" or Soft Copy" and the price will change accordingly. Then depending on the option chosen, after payment, the customer will get a confirmation email for the hard copy, while for the soft copy they will also get the download link.

I have installed Commerce File to cover the soft copy option, since Drupal Commerce handles the hard copy option out of the box (being a manual shipping process), however I cannot see how this can be done using this module. I have created a commerce file product which allows for soft copies, and a standard product which allows for the hard copies; but how do I create a product that has both of these as an option? Is Commerce File not the module for this?

Answer (score 0):

After some more experimenting I have worked it out. For any sort of product variations you need to edit the Product reference field. Change the field to a select list and also make sure the you set the number of values to unlimited (or at least more than 1). This will then create a drop down list which when changed will switch between the different products within the same node. I hope that this helps!